# wireless card not found

Tags: drivers

I did a clean install of ubuntu 16.04. The toshiba..Saellite use to have kali linux on it but it stopped working.. So I did a clean install of ubuntu 16.04. I prefure to use kali linux in a VM. I wanted ubuntu to take to school. Sence I am taking computer management classes.

I tried doing lsusb and it isn't even finding the wireless card

lspci -v this command shows realtex simiconductor rtl8108/2/6e pce express... but nothing about wireless?

I have tried doing FN8 but nothing happen to show if the wireless is turn on or off?

I don't know what drivers to try to install so see if that fixs the problem.
or is is hardware?